# How to encourage & support my piano student who walked off the stage in frustration?

Tags: performing, teaching

Last weekend was the recital for a music school near me. One of my students walked off the stage in frustration.  She is a sweet teenager and is talented also.

I wonder what words can I use to encourage and build her confidence up?

Comment: Welcome! I'm glad you're looking to help her. This question needs some fine-tuning, though. First, glance over [the topics that are covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Stage fright and frustration definitely fall among these topics, and there's been a lot asked and answered about them here already; try searching some of the past questions. Check out also [how to avoid subjective answers](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). And finally, every student (and teacher) is different. Can you tell any more about the specific challenge she's facing? One might...

Comment: ... One might leave the stage in a lot of different moods (terror, embarrassment, anger) and for a lot of reasons (generalized social anxiety, specific concerns about this piece, overall frustration at self, build up of stress from lots of external sources). And while I would definitely connect with her, I wouldn't assume that "magic words" could fix everything. I'd start by listening most of all!

Comment: Finally, although the question-and-answer format here isn't intended to cater to open-ended broad discussion, there is also a chat channel where all the rules about valid questions don't apply. You need 20 points to participate, but that can be gained very easily.

Comment: Thank you, that was a great answer. Have a great day Andy Bonner:)

Comment: Did she _want_ to perform at the recital or was she _required_ to do it?

Comment: @MichaelCurtis is on the right track here. Problems like the one your student encountered have there origins long before the recital itself. I think the question to be asked is where your preparation of the student fell short. It sounds like the student is continuing with lessons, so you needn't say anything unless the student brings it up. On the other hand, you can investigate your own approach to give the student a better experience in the future.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about interpersonal skills, not music. Questions about stage fright might be on-topic, how to handle someone who has it isn't. It's also likely to be answered with opinions, not facts.

Answer (score 1):

Is she STILL your student?  She returned for her next lesson?  Good.   Let her raise the subject if she wants to.  Listen, don't try to 'fix it'.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to be human.  Go with Laurence's answer first... leave it alone unless she brings it up.  Then, share a story from your own life about a frustrating or difficult/embarrassing situation you lived through.  Sometimes it helps to know that even the "experts" stumble along the way.